# How to get the selected values of jquery-bonsai tree using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get selected (checked) values from a tree structure which was created using jquery-bonsai (link : http://simonwade.me/jquery-bonsai/)

My code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://bgagenomics.iicb.res.in/bga/arup/js/assets/svg-icons.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://bgagenomics.iicb.res.in/bga/arup/js/jquery.bonsai.css' />       
    <script src='http://bgagenomics.iicb.res.in/bga/arup/js/jquery.bonsai.js'></script>
    <script src='http://bgagenomics.iicb.res.in/bga/arup/js/jquery.qubit.js'> </script>

    <script>
        jQuery(function() {
            $('#auto-checkboxes').bonsai({
            expandAll: false,
            checkboxes: true, // qbit plung helper
            createInputs: 'checkbox' // enebles auto click data-checked
            });
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#val").click(function()
            {
                alert("hello"); //need help here
            });     
});
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
        <ol id='auto-checkboxes' data-name='foo'>
        <li data-value='0'>All
            <ol>
                <li data-value='1'>One</li>
            <li data-value='2' data-id='2'>
                Two
                <ol>
                <li data-name='baz' data-value='3'>
                    Three
                    <ol>
                    <li data-name='baz' data-value='4'>Four</li>
                    </ol>
                </li>
                <li data-value='5'>Five</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <br>
    <input id ="val" type="image" value = "Result" />

    <body>
</html>
```

The above code will create the tree stucture like

[image]

I would like to get checked values on clicking on the **result** .

Any help or suggestion to solve the above issue will be a great help.

Answer (score 2):

You can get values of all selected checkbox by looping through ol finding selected checkbox as:

```
var yourArray = [];//global variable
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#val").click(function() {
        yourArray = [];//unset previous values
        $("input:checkbox[name=yourCheckboxName]:checked").each(function(){
            yourArray.push($(this).val());
        });
     });     
});
```